# How do we configure MobileFirst Analytics queue sizes in WAS ND?

Tags: websphere, jndi, ibm-mobilefirst

We are working with MobileFirst Platform 7.0 on WebSphere ND (*not* Liberty). With Liberty, it is possible to configure analytics queue sizes [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26453955/27641).

However, on WAS ND, we don't see the properties `wl.analytics.queues` or `wl.analytics.queue.size` available for either our MobileFirst project WAR, or the MobileFirst administration WAR.

How can we set these JNDI properties?

Comment: If it should be read from JNDI, then you can try to configure it via admin console in `Environment > Naming > Namespace bindings`. Create new `String` entries there.

Comment: Gas, we tried that, but are getting Namespace exceptions when starting the server. Do you know what the fully-qualified name of the properties should be? (i.e. in `XYZ/wl.analytics.queues`, what is XYZ?)

Comment: What exceptions are you receiving? Looking at that Liberty config you provided, there shouldn't be any XYZ.

Comment: I'll dig out the exact one. Perhaps there shouldn't be; we'll retry without it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As of MobileFirst Platform v7.0, this JNDI is no longer available.

The process of forwarding logs to the MFP Analytics server has been optimized in such a way that setting this property is unnecessary.  Your logs should be visible in your MFP Operational Analytics console in close to real time.

Comment: Aha, I didn't know that. Thank you for the clarification.

Comment: Prior to v7.0, this queue was also volatile, in that sense that if queues became full, messages were thrown away (and thus analytics couldn't be relied on as a system of record). Can you clarify what's changed and how this now works?